# What are the key points to consider when creating a library of semi-complex web widgets?

Tags: api, widget, components

For the last year, I have delivered several relatively simple single-page apps, essentially almost-alike mortgage and financing calculators, to various customers. These have either been the sole focus of a page, or sidebar apps beside some main content. Since these apps differ by very little else than styling, layout, and a few customer specific parameters, it would mean a high ROI if these SPAs could be consolidated into some kind of library.

How one would go about in doing it in practice is a bit more unclear. What are the key points to consider and/or avoid when creating a library of pre-made interactive components?

They need to

- be custom-styled per customer (custom widths, heights, fonts, etc)
- not clash with other page elements
- ... ?

It seems unwise (inflexible) to pre-render html and inline css on the server side, and maybe some kind of half-baked JSON representation would be more appropriate, where the actual assembly would be controlled by some javascript, and styling would be done on the client based on some default stylesheet we provide. Or maybe somehow use GWT (we are a Java shop) to create the widgets.

I am out of my depths here so input would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, possibly a better way to think of this is not creating a library, but creating a "calculator" application (widget) that can be configured for different kinds of calculations and to be themeable

So your focus is on how to create it so you can configure it for different functionality.

Comment: Good for one type of calculator, but there are other types pf calculators than what I mentioned, and these can have very different layouts and inputs, so creating one SuperCalculator is not really possible IMHO.

Comment: Any ideas on technology to achieve this? For instance, could I use GWT to create embeddable widgets in non-GTW pages? Manually create html + inline css (maintenance nightmare; how would one edit this later on) that can be fetched by JSONP?

Comment: And where would you apply styling, and how would you make it easy to customize it for each customer without changing the code? We could supply a custom css per customer for a bare-bones rendered html structure, or do it server-side.